# Retrieve current location when application is in background

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, appdelegate

I've built an application where you can press a start button. Once the button is pressed the application will get user location every 10 second all the way till the stop button is pressed. When I leave the application or if the screen gets black, it will NOT get any more locations till I re-enter the application.

So, I'm currently trying to update the locations when the application is minimized. (I guess it's called in the background?), and also when the screen turns black. But my questions is:

1. Should I write this code in the AppDelegate?, if so. How can I know
   if the button was pressed or not?
2. Where exactly in the AppDelegate should I add the code? And how can
   I pass the locations back to the correct ViewController? (Since I
   cannot make any prepare for segue from AppDelegate)

If you know the answers of this questions, please do not hesitate to answer them. :) I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Did you get a permission from user to use location services while the user is using other apps?

Comment: @RamyMohamed I'm not sure about that permission. But I've activated the "Location updates" in "Background Modes"

I've also set 2 permissions in the info-plist which is:
*Location always 
and
*Location When in use

Comment: check this blog out: https://medium.com/curbside/requesting-location-permissions-in-ios-9e5a3b814a8b

Comment: @RamyMohamed Alright, done reading. And it's activated. :) But where should I start writing the code for this?

Comment: So, you want to update the locations at regular intervals, say every 10 seconds, when the app is in background. To achieve this, you need to run timer to fetch the location at regular intervals. But it is not possible to run the timer when the app is in background. As soon as apps enter BG, it will be suspended sooner. You can either use Significant Location Service or Geo Fencing service to update the location when the app is in BG. These both services will work even when the app is terminated.

Comment: @Anand Do you have any codes to show that? Or documentation/tutorial? :) Thanks for your input!

Comment: SLC and Geo Fencing has its own caveats like accuracy will not be correct, cannot configure intervals and so on. Once you go through this document, you will understand more: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/using_the_significant-change_location_service

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get user's location in background is to use the Significant-Change Location Service according to [apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/using_the_significant-change_location_service) put this func in your class:

```
func startReceivingSignificantLocationChanges() {
    let authorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    if authorizationStatus != .authorizedAlways {
    // User has not authorized access to location information.
        return
    } 

    if !CLLocationManager.significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable() {
    // The service is not available.
        return
    }
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
}
```

and also this func:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,  didUpdateLocations 
    locations: [CLLocation]) {
       let lastLocation = locations.last!
           
       // Do something with the location. 
}
```

so you just need to call startReceivingSignificantLocationChanges() inside your button and it will call locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]), so do what you want with the location there.

Remember to ask permission to use location and to stop tracking with `locationManager.stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()`

Comment: Very interesting! So. I do not need to call anything in the app delegate? And according to your first snippet. I should not do anything inside the brackets at:
// User has not authorized access to location information & // The service is not available.?

Comment: Alright, the code is added to my application.

Just one question:
How can I automatically update it after around 10 seconds? or after a few meters? I mean, I need it to be updated very often. I hope you get me, thanks!

Comment: 'I do not need to call anything in the app delegate?'
No, not for this anyway
'I should not do anything inside the brackets'
you should handle it,maybe you could show a pop up warning the user, or something like that

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Anyway, I've added that code to my application. But how often does it update? Every 500meter or so? I need to to update very common, like every 20meter, or every 10 second. Is that possible? Thanks.

Comment: if you really need to update more often then this code does ( around 500m), you should see this link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/using_the_standard_location_service

Comment: you should see the link i send before, it is what you are looking for, but i did not implemented it yet, so maybe wait for someone else to help

Comment: @Putte, You cannot configure SLC service to return location update every 500 meters. You can just start or stop this service. This service will return the location  when some significant distance is travelled and the returned location will have lower accuracy compared to Standard Location service. This is bcoz SLC uses cell tower and crowd sourced wifi and Standard uses GPS.

Comment: @Putte, In SLC, Apple did not define the significant distance also. So, its totally up to Apple to return the location data. There will also be some minimum duration between two consecutive location data in SLC which is again undefined by Apple.

Comment: @Putte, hope you got the code in link shared by Eduardo above. Please let me know if that did not help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Take location permission for Always Allow
2. Set location manager for allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates  true
   from the above way you can get location in every location changes store this information and it send  to server. Below is the sample code

   typealias LocateMeCallback = (_ location: CLLocation?) -> Void

   ```
   /*
    LocationTracker to track the user in while navigating from one place to other and store new locations in locations array.
    **/
   class LocationTracker: NSObject {

   static let shared = LocationTracker()

   var lastLocation: CLLocation?
   var locations: [CLLocation] = []

   var previousLocation: CLLocation?
   var isPreviousIsSameAsCurrent: Bool {
       if let previous = previousLocation, let last = lastLocation {
          return previous == last
       }
       return false
   }
   var isAggressiveModeOn = false
   var locationManager: CLLocationManager = {
      let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
      locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
      locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = true
      locationManager.activityType = .automotiveNavigation
      return locationManager
   }()

   var locateMeCallback: LocateMeCallback?

   var isCurrentLocationAvailable: Bool {
       if lastLocation != nil {
         return true
       }
       return false
   }

   func enableLocationServices() {
       locationManager.delegate = self
       switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
       case .notDetermined:
           // Request when-in-use authorization initially
           locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
       case .restricted, .denied:
           // Disable location features
           print("Fail permission to get current location of user")
       case .authorizedWhenInUse:
           // Enable basic location features
           enableMyWhenInUseFeatures()
      case .authorizedAlways:
           // Enable any of your app's location features
           enableMyAlwaysFeatures()
      }
   }

   func enableMyWhenInUseFeatures() {
      locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
      locationManager.delegate = self
      escalateLocationServiceAuthorization()
   }

   func escalateLocationServiceAuthorization() {
       // Escalate only when the authorization is set to when-in-use
       if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse {
           locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
       }
   }

   func enableMyAlwaysFeatures() {
      enableCoarseLocationFetch()
      locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
      locationManager.delegate = self
   }

   // Enable Rough Location Fetch
   func enableCoarseLocationFetch() {
      isAggressiveModeOn = false
      locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer
      locationManager.distanceFilter = 100

   }

   // Enable Aggressive Location Fetch
   func enableAggressiveLocationFetch() {
       isAggressiveModeOn = true
       locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
       locationManager.distanceFilter = 10

   }

   func locateMe(callback: @escaping LocateMeCallback) {
       self.locateMeCallback = callback
       if lastLocation == nil {
           enableLocationServices()
       } else {
          callback(lastLocation)
       }
   }

   func startTracking() {
        enableLocationServices()
   }

   func stopTracking() {
       locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
   }

   func resetPreviousLocation() {
       previousLocation = nil
   }

   private override init() {}
   ```

   }

   ```
   extension LocationTracker: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

       func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {


           print(locations)
           guard let location = locations.first else { return }
           guard -location.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceNow < 120, // Validate only location fetched recently
               location.horizontalAccuracy > 0, // Validate Horizontal Accuracy - Ve means Invalid
               location.horizontalAccuracy < 200 // Validate Horizontal Accuracy > 100 M
               else {
               print("invalid location received OR ignore old (cached) updates")
               return
           }

           self.locations.append(location)
           lastLocation = location


           if let activeRide = RideManager.shared.activeRide,
               let _ = AccessTokenHelper.shared.accessToken,
               let activeRideId = activeRide.ride_id,
               let type = activeRide.rideStatusTypeOptional,
               type == .started  {
               //Store Location For A particular Ride after Start
               LocationUpdater.shared.saveInDataBase(rideId: activeRideId, locations: [location])
           }

       }

       func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
           print(error.localizedDescription)
       }

       func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
           enableLocationServices()
       }

   }


   /*
    This class having responsibility of Updating the location on server after n second and update path after n second.
    **/
   class LocationTimer {
       static let time: Double = 30
   }

   /*
     class to update locations to server after nth second
    **/
   class LocationUpdater: NSObject {

       static let shared = LocationUpdater(n: Double(LocationTimer.time), tracker: LocationTracker.shared)

       let n: Double
       private let tracker: LocationTracker
       var timer: Timer! = nil

       init(n: Double, tracker: LocationTracker) {
           self.n = n
           self.tracker = tracker
           super.init()
       }

       func startUpdater() {
           self.timer?.invalidate()
           self.timer = nil
           self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: n, target: self, selector: #selector(updateLocationsToServer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
           self.timer.fire()
       }

       func stopUpdater() {
           self.timer?.invalidate()
           self.timer = nil
       }

       @objc func updateLocationsToServer() {
   // update to server
    }
   }


   // usage 
   LocationTracker.shared.startTracking()
   LocationUpdater.shared.startUpdater()
   ```